# Find common elements in two unsorted array

Tags: java

I try to find a solution to this problem:
I have two arrays A and B of integers (A and B can have different dimensions). I have to find the common elements in these two arrays. I have another condition: the maximum distance between the common elements is k.
So, this is my solution. I think is correct:

```
for (int i = 0; i<A.length; i++){
    for (int j=jlimit; (j<B.length) && (j <= ks); j++){
        if(A[i]==B[j]){
            System.out.println(B[j]);
            jlimit = j;
            ks = j+k;
        }//end if
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make a better solution? Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `if(A[i]==B[j])` only works for primitive types. For reference types there is a difference between equality and identity. You don't tell us what `A` and `B` are exactly.

Comment: I see 2 interpretations for the `k distance`: a) You are guaranteed that the distance between an item appearing in the two arrays is `k` or less, or b) If an element is repeated but the distance is greater than `k`, do not report it as repeated. The two interpretations may lead to different implementations and results, which one is right?

Comment: ok, the distance between them is k or less.

Comment: Your logic for setting `jlimit` and `ks` seems wrong. Have you actually tested your code at all?

Comment: yes, i tested it.. and it work.. i tried different input.

Comment: So we are assuming that "distance k" is about index difference here. Generally when talking about distances it means value distance (like the Levenshtein distance for words http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). Or for ints we would have `Math.abs(v - w) < k` if v and w are the values we are comparing... in which case this solution is totally O(N*M) ~ O(N^2). Then, you'd better sort and search in order to obtain O(N.logN) performances.

Comment: Your algorithm does not seem to work for A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, B = {4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5} and with k of 5. I would assume that the result should be 2, 4 and 5. I think you have to broaden your search span to something like `for (int j = Math.max(0, i - k); (j<B.length) && (j <= i + k); j++){`

Answer (score 5):

Given your explanation, I think the most direct approach is reading array A, putting all elements in a `Set` (setA), do the same with B (setB), and use the `retainAll` method to find the intersection of both sets (items that belong to both of the sets).

You will see that the `k distance` is not used at all, but I see no way to use that condition that leads to code either faster or more maintenable. The solution I advocate works without enforcing that condition, so it works also when the condition is true (that is called "weakening the preconditions")

Comment: Fun improvement on this: Use a BloomFilter (very nice little data structure) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter. There is an implementation in Guava.

Answer (score 5):

IMPLEMENT BINARY SEARCH AND QUICK SORT!

this will lead to tons of code.... but the fastest result.

You can sort the elements of the larger array with like quick sort which would lead to O(nlogn).

then iterate through the smaller array for each value and do a binary search of that particular element in the other array. Add some logic for the distance in the binary search.

I think you can get the complexity down to O(nlogn). Worst case O(n^2)

pseudo code.

```
larger array equals a
other array equals b

sort a

iterate through b
       binary search b at iterated index
     // I would throw (last index - index) logic in binary search
     // to exit out of that even faster by returning "NOT FOUND" as soon as that is hit.
       if found && (last index - index) is less than or equal 
          store last index
          print value
```

this is the fastest way possible to do your problem i believe.

Comment: yes i know that sorting the arrays i have a better solution but this two arrays are read only.

Comment: sorting the arrays will make any k distance logic not work because the new indexes mean nothing.

Comment: Ah.... i was thinking about that differently that makes more sense now.. i thought it essentially meant the amount of common elements.

Answer (score 2):

Although this would be a *cheat*, since it uses `HashSet`s, it is pretty nice for a Java implementation of this algorithm. If you need the pseudocode for the algorithm, don't read any further.

Source and author in the JavaDoc. Cheers.

```
/**
 * @author Crunchify.com
 */
public class CrunchifyIntersection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Integer[ ] arrayOne = { 1, 4, 5, 2, 7, 3, 9 };
         Integer[ ] arrayTwo = { 5, 2, 4, 9, 5 };

         Integer[ ] common = iCrunchIntersection.findCommon( arrayOne, arrayTwo );

         System.out.print( "Common Elements Between Two Arrays: " );       
         for( Integer entry : common ) {
              System.out.print( entry + " " );
         }
   }

   public static Integer[ ] findCommon( Integer[ ] arrayOne, Integer[ ] arrayTwo ) {

        Integer[ ] arrayToHash;
        Integer[ ] arrayToSearch;

        if( arrayOne.length < arrayTwo.length ) {
            arrayToHash = arrayOne;
            arrayToSearch = arrayTwo;
        } else {
            arrayToHash = arrayTwo;
            arrayToSearch = arrayOne;
        }

        HashSet<Integer> intersection = new HashSet<Integer>( );

        HashSet<Integer> hashedArray = new HashSet<Integer>( );
        for( Integer entry : arrayToHash ) {
            hashedArray.add( entry );
        }

        for( Integer entry : arrayToSearch ) {
            if( hashedArray.contains( entry ) ) {
                intersection.add( entry );
            }
        }

        return intersection.toArray( new Integer[ 0 ] );
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation is roughly O(A.length*2k).

That seems to be about the best you're going to do if you want to maintain your **"no more than k away" logic**, as that **rules out sorting and the use of sets**. I would alter a little to make your code more understandable.

1. First, I would ensure that you iterate over the smaller of the two arrays. This would make the complexity O(min(A.length, B.length)*2k).

   To understand the purpose of this, consider the case where `A` has 1 element and `B` has 100. In this case, we are only going to perform one iteration in the outer loop, and k iterations in the inner loop.

   Now consider when `A` has 100 elements, and `B` has 1. In this case, we will perform 100 iterations on the outer loop, and 1 iteration each on the inner loop.

   If k is less than the length of your long array, iterating over the shorter array in the outer loop will be more efficient.
2. Then, I would change how you're calculating the k distance stuff just for readability's sake. The code I've written demonstrates this.

Here's what I would do:

```
//not sure what type of array we're dealing with here, so I'll assume int.
int[] toIterate;
int[] toSearch;

if (A.length > B.length)
{
    toIterate = B;
    toSearch = A;
}
else
{
    toIterate = A;
    toSearch = B;
}

for (int i = 0; i < toIterate.length; i++)
{
    // set j to k away in the negative direction
    int j = i - k;

    if (j < 0) 
        j = 0;

    // only iterate until j is k past i
    for (; (j < toSearch.length) && (j <= i + k); j++)
    {
        if(toIterate[i] == toSearch[j])
        {
            System.out.println(toSearch[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Your use of `jlimit` and `ks` may work, but handling your k distance like this is more understandable for your average programmer (and it's marginally more efficient).

Comment: ok, i try to compare my solution with your.. i think is better your.. thanks in advance..have a good day!!

Comment: @user1841492 Glad to be of assistance. If you use this solution (or some other solution), please accept it.

Comment: Just a question in the second cycle for it starts from j = 0 right?

Comment: Unless k is an order of magnitude smaller than N (the size of the arrays) then you have a bad O(N^2) algorithm here, no?

Comment: @user1841492 It depends on your k value and where you are in the outer iteration. The inner loop will start from 0 if `(i - k) < 0`.

Comment: @le_douard Yes, this is basically O(n^2), but it's also the only solution here that actually takes into consideration the k-distance problem presented by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

**O(N) solution (BloomFilters):**

Here is a solution using bloom filters (implementation is from the Guava library)

```
public static <T> T findCommon_BloomFilterImpl(T[] A, T[] B, Funnel<T> funnel) {
    BloomFilter<T> filter = BloomFilter.create(funnel, A.length + B.length);
    for (T t : A) {
        filter.put(t);
    }
    for (T t : B) {
        if (filter.mightContain(t)) {
            return t;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

use it like this:

```
    Integer j = Masking.findCommon_BloomFilterImpl(new Integer[]{12, 2, 3, 4, 5222, 622, 71, 81, 91, 10}, new Integer[]{11, 100, 15, 18, 79, 10}, Funnels.integerFunnel());
    Assert.assertNotNull(j);
    Assert.assertEquals(10, j.intValue());
```

Runs in O(N) since calculating hash for Integer is pretty straight forward. So still O(N) if you can reduce the calculation of hash of your elementents to O(1) or a small O(K) where K is the size of each element.

**O(N.LogN) solution (sorting and iterating):**

Sorting and the iterating through the array will lead you to a O(N*log(N)) solution:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T findCommon(T[] A, T[] B, Class<T> clazz) {
    T[] array = concatArrays(A, B, clazz);
    Arrays.sort(array);
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i - 1].equals(array[i])) {     //put your own equality check here
            return array[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

`concatArrays(~)` is in O(N) of course. `Arrays.sort(~)` is a bi-pivot implementation of QuickSort with complexity in O(N.logN), and iterating through the array again is O(N).

So we have O((N+2).logN) ~> O(N.logN).

As a general case solution (withouth the "within k" condition of your problem) is better than yours. It should be considered for k "close to" N in your precise case.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution if arrays are already sorted

```
 public static void get_common_courses(Integer[] courses1, Integer[] courses2) {
        // Sort both arrays if input is not sorted 
        //Arrays.sort(courses1);
        //Arrays.sort(courses2);
        int i=0, j=0;
        while(i<courses1.length && j<courses2.length) {
            if(courses1[i] > courses2[j]) {
                j++;
            } else if(courses1[i] < courses2[j]){
                i++;
            } else {
                System.out.println(courses1[i]);
                i++;j++;
            }
        }
}
```

Apache commons collections API has done this in efficient way without sorting

```
    public static Collection intersection(final Collection a, final Collection b) {
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    Map mapa = getCardinalityMap(a);
    Map mapb = getCardinalityMap(b);
    Set elts = new HashSet(a);
    elts.addAll(b);
    Iterator it = elts.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        Object obj = it.next();
        for(int i=0,m=Math.min(getFreq(obj,mapa),getFreq(obj,mapb));i<m;i++) {
            list.add(obj);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: You are ignoring the additional complexities of `getCardinalityMap` and `Math.min`

Answer (score 1):

Solution using Java 8

```
static <T> Collection<T> intersection(Collection<T> c1, Collection<T> c2) {
    if (c1.size() < c2.size())
        return intersection(c2, c1);
    Set<T> c2set = new HashSet<>(c2);
    return c1.stream().filter(c2set::contains).distinct().collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Use Arrays::asList and boxed values of primitives:

```
Integer[] a =...    
Collection<Integer> res = intersection(Arrays.asList(a),Arrays.asList(b));
```

Answer (score 0):

Generic solution

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] a = { "a", "b" };
    String[] b = { "c", "b" };
    String[] intersection = intersection(a, b, a[0].getClass());
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intersection));
    Integer[] aa = { 1, 3, 4, 2 };
    Integer[] bb = { 1, 19, 4, 5 };
    Integer[] intersectionaabb = intersection(aa, bb, aa[0].getClass());
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intersectionaabb));
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <T> T[] intersection(T[] a, T[] b, Class<? extends T> c) {
    HashSet<T> s = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(a));
    s.retainAll(Arrays.asList(b));
    return s.toArray((T[]) Array.newInstance(c, s.size()));
}
```

**Output**

```
[b]
[1, 4]
```